# Rails i18n: Translation missing problem, locale not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale

I have a problem with a Rails 2.3.8 application. I'm using rails i18n to make the site in different languages. Everything works perfect, everywhere, except one place.

After successful signup, I do:

```
flash[:notice] = t 'path.to.locale.key'
```

Just as I do everywhere else.

But that renders the following:

```
translation missing: 'locale.path.to.locale.key' not found
```

It seems it's not loading the current locale (or else it will say 'en', or 'es', or whatever instead of 'locale').

Any idea that could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you overwrite it somewhere down that yml file. Maybe you did too many nesting. Maybe that key has subkeys.

Delete everything from that locale.yml and place only that message and see if it works.

The problem you are having happens to me every now and then, and it's always something I messed up in yml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a default locale in your ApplicationController, for example with a before_filter:

```
I18n.locale = params[:locale] || 'en'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this happened to me in mailer classes after I upgraded to Rails 4.1. It was working correctly on Rails 3 and there was no change on yml files. Somehow i18n did not see the default locale.
So I've added this line on mailer class to fix out.

```
 I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale

class ProviderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Resque::Mailer
  default from: APP_CONFIG.mailer.from

  def registration_email(provider)
    @provider = provider
    I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
    @provider_url  = "#{APP_CONFIG.base_url}/hizmetsgl/#{provider['_id']}"
    @howto_url  = "#{APP_CONFIG.base_url}/hizmetverenler"
    mail(to: provider["business_email"], subject: t('provider_mailer.registration_email.subject')) 
  end

end
```